# On android calling a method that calls listener throws exception

Tags: android

On android calling a method that calls listener throws exception "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can"
here is my code:

```
public class MyClassAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, ProfileInfo> {
private Context mContext;
private IGetTelegramUserInfoAsync mListener;

protected ProfileInfo doInBackground(String... params) {
// .... some code
  mListener.GetResult(profileInfo)
// ...
helperMethod();
}

private void helperMethod(){
  mListener.GetResult(profileInfo); //exception place

}
```

Comment: why you are using AsyncTask if you are using api which is already asynchronous?

Comment: just do whatever you need to do with that result in `onPostExecute()` method (unblock UI, parse it, whatever)

Comment: @Selvin it told im new to java and android! and i used AsyncTask Because there are many aync calls in the method

Comment: Why on earth are you doing an asynchronous call if you're already on a background thread?

Answer (score 0):

You might do it by calling a listener
Define a listener like this:

```
public interface YourListener {
    public void gotResultOfYourAsync();
}
```

Call it in this way or implement in in your Activity or Fragment :

```
public class Something {
private YourListener yourListener;

public void setTheListener(YourListener listener) {
    yourListener = listener;
}
```

//inside of your Async task you can call this

```
   yourListener.gotResultOfYourAsync();
```

it is a little complicated but you can ask your questions

Comment: I found a good example of implementation:https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners

Comment: You are welcome. At the moment I'm busy. I will see your question tonight.